# People Picker not working for cross forest users

Tags: active-directory, forms-authentication, people-picker

I have cross forest users which I want to add to my SharePoint Enterprise site but the people picker is not able to pick up those users?

Can someone help.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your ActiveDirectory Trust, you have to configure some stuff in PeoplePicker to be able to browse foreign Forests.

This need still be done with STSADM.EXE in SharePoint 2013, as there are no PowerShell-CMDlets for this.

More Information can be found in Technet:
Configure People Picker in SharePoint 2013
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg602075%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: Ran that command but still no luck.

Comment: Could you tell me the exact command you executed? Also some imformation abour your forest-configuration would be interesting for better understanding (names, trust-configuration)